# How to test Angular 6 service with dependency that uses private methods/properties to modify output of public methods/properties

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, angular6

I'm stuck on trying to write a Jasmine/Karma test in an Angular 6 app for a service which depends on another service, and that dependency has several private properties/methods that modify how the public method executes, and my test always fail.

All the code is working as expected during run time but I don't get how to test this correctly. I've tried spies for the private methods and properties which doesn't work, nor does changing them to public. Clearly I'm missing something.

Right now, I don't care or want to test `DependencyService`. I want to be able to test `MyService` function `doSomething` works, currently it always returns `null` so my test output is `Failed: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of null`. Removing the `if` statement in `postData()` returns the observable as expected and the test passes.

It feels I'm spying on the wrong things here as my test is becoming tightly coupled with the dependency service or `localStorage` values.

How do I mock/spy on the `checkAuth` and `isAuth` in my service dependency? Perhaps more accurately, how do I test `doSomething()` correctly so that the test is isolated to the `MyService` service?

```js
export class MyService {
    constructor(private depService: DependencyService) { }

    public doSomething(additionalPayload: Object) {
        const payload = { ...additionalPayload, modified: true };
        return this.depService.postData('/api/endpoint', payload);
    }

}

export class DependencyService {
    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

    private isAuth: boolean = false;

    private checkAuth() {
        const token = localStorage.get('token');
        if (token !== null) {
            this.isAuth = true;
        } else {
            this.isAuth = false;
        }
    }

    postData(url, body): Observable<any> {
        this.checkAuth();
        if (!this.isAuth) {
            return null;
        }
        return this.httpClient.post(url, body);
    }
}
```

The `myservice.spec.ts` so far which isn't passing:

```js
describe('MyService', () => {
  let httpTestingController: HttpTestingController;

  let myService: MyService;
  let dependencyServiceSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<DependencyService>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    const dependencyServiceSpyObj = jasmine.createSpyObj('DependencyService', ['postData']);

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ HttpClientTestingModule ],
      providers: [
        MyService,
        { provide: DependencyService, useValue: dependencyServiceSpyObj },
      ]
    });

    httpTestingController = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);

    myService = TestBed.get(MyService);
    dependencyServiceSpy = TestBed.get(DependencyService);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    httpTestingController.verify();
  });

  it('#doSomething should post some data', async(() => {
    const payloadData: Object = {
      name: 'Ash',
      food: 'donut'
    };

    const responseData: Object = {
      success: true,
      msg: 'Payload received'
    };

    // HELP HERE ↓
    // need to spy/mock dependencyService.isAuth so that it is `true`
    // otherwise inside `postData` the if statement will always return a `null` value
    // ...spy/mock `localStorage`?
    dependencyServiceSpy.postData.and.returnValue(/* return http observable so that .subscribe can be called */);

    myService.doSomething(payloadData).subscribe(data => {
      expect(data).toEqual(responseData);
    }, fail);

    const req = httpTestingController.expectOne('/api/endpoint');

    expect(req.request.method).toEqual('POST');
    expect(req.request.body).toEqual({ ...payloadData, modified: true });

    expect(dependencyServiceSpy.postData.calls.count()).toBe(1);
    expect(dependencyServiceSpy.postData.calls.mostRecent().returnValue).toBe(responseData);

    req.flush(responseData);
  }));
});
```

Comment: Not related to your issue but your use of `: Object` as a type annotation is a bad practice and corresponds to a misunderstanding of the language. Remove it.

Comment: @AluanHaddad in the actual app the types are defined as something more meaningful, I only added `: Object` here for demonstration purposes. It's not relevant to the question.

Comment: But your annotation is actually removing information. I agree that importing arbitrary types into the example would be bad, but why annotate when the compiler will infer something better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need not worry about the dependency service. If the user is authenticated or if network calls are being made correctly or not should be a part of the spec for dependency service.

There is also an issue with the way you spy `dependencyService`. `TestBed.get(DependencyService)` return the current instance of `DependencyService`, and not the spy. Would be wise to rename the variable as below:

```
let dependencyService: DependencyService;
```

and the assignment as below:

```
dependencyService = TestBed.get(DependencyService);
```

You just need to spy `postData` method.

From the perspective of `MyService`, there are only two scenarios for `DependencyService`.

1. **User is not authenticated**

   In this case, all you need is that `postData` should return null. You need not worry about `checkAuth`. You can spy on the `postData` and return Observable with null value. You are only concerned about the output of `postData` method, not how the output is generated.

   ```
   it('#doSomething should return null if user is not authenticated', () => {
       const payloadData = {
           name: 'Ash',
           food: 'donut'
       };

       spyOn(dependencyService, 'postData').and.returnValue(Observable.create(observer => {
           observer.next(null);
           observer.complete();
       }));

       myService.doSomething('/api/endpoint', payloadData).subscribe(data => {
           expect(data).toBeNull();
       }, fail);

   });
   ```

   As you can see above, you need not specify how `postData` arrives at returning null. You know that in this scenario `postData` should return null. How it is achieved needs to tested in the spec of `DependencyService`.
2. **User is authenticated**

   In this case, `postData` returns the value from HTTP call. Again, you just need to return the value. If the network call is made correctly or not is to be tested in the spec of `DependencyService`.

   ```
   it('#doSomething should post some data', () => {
       const payloadData = {
           name: 'Ash',
           food: 'donut'
       };

       const responseData = {
           success: true,
           msg: 'Payload received'
       };

       spyOn(dependencyService, 'postData').and.returnValue(Observable.create(observer => {
           observer.next(responseData);
           observer.complete();
       }));

       myService.doSomething('/api/endpoint', payloadData).subscribe(data => {
           expect(data).toEqual(responseData);
       }, fail);

   });
   ```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the way I spy vs your suggestion? I followed one of the examples from https://v6.angular.io/guide/testing#angular-testbed (`Ctrl+f` for `jasmine.SpyObj<ValueService>` as an example). In your example is it still possible to assert on the spy tracking properties? E.g. `expect(dependencyService.postData.calls.count()).toBe(1)`

Comment: @Ash My bad. I didn't notice that you injected a `dependencyServiceSpyObj` in the `providers` array. Your approach would also work. Sorry about that.

Comment: If you want to check other properties of the spy (as in my approach), you could assign the spy to a variable and check: 

    `const postDataSpy = spyOn(dependencyService, 'postData').and.returnValue(...);
    expect(postDataSpy.calls.count()).toBe(1);`

Comment: Thanks, and for clarifying not needing to care about dependency service. Correct me here if I'm wrong but in my question I `expect(req.request.method).toEqual('POST')` while testing `MyService` and importing `HttpTestingController`. Since the http request is actually occurring with the dependency service, I shouldn't care about it in the test suite for `MyService`. This is why we can use the spy and `Observer.create`. Is this correct?

Comment: Correct. You can remove `HttpTestingController` and all HTTP request testing from `MyService`. They need to be in `DependencyService` spec.

Comment: Cleaning up my test and when removing `imports: [HttpClientTestingModule]` I get the error `Error: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[DependencyService -> HttpClient] ... No provider for HttpClient`. But this shouldn't happen because `MyService` doesn't use `HttpClient`, only `DependencyService` does. Any idea why this happens and is your approach a false positive?

Comment: How are you providing `DependencyService`? Is it the original service or a mock?
If it is the original service, it has a dependency on `HttpClient`.

Comment: No mock, providing the original `DependencyService`, so I guess I'll need to import the `HttpClientTestingModule` in the `MyService` test suite.

Comment: Or better, provide a mock service. 

`class MockDependencyService{
postData(a,b){}
}`
and in providers `{provide: DependencyService, useClass: MockDependencyService}`